# Unrequested user logins with Facebook for Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

The observable behaviour is the following:

- Open auth activity
- Login using facebook sdk button
- Logout (close session)
- Kill app
- Open app
- Open auth activity again
- Facebook automatically logins the user, just by opening the activity

Some code - from the auth activity:

```
    // Facebook callback
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };
    // Facebook Helper
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    ...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
        fbAuthBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fbAuthButton);
        fbAuthBtn.setApplicationId(getString(R.string.fb_app_id));

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    }
    ...
    /**
     * Facebook session state changed
    */
    public void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
      if (state.isOpened()) {
        // Logged In
        if (User.getInstance().authenticationType != UserAuthenticationMethod.FACEBOOK) {
            showProgress();

            FacebookAuthenticator fbAuth = new FacebookAuthenticator(this, handlerFacebook);
            fbAuth.authenticate();
            }
       } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        // Logged Out
        User.getInstance().logout();
       }
    }
```

I implement logout as follows:

```
public void logout() {
    ...
    // Logout Facebook
    Session fbSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (fbSession != null) {
        fbSession.close();
    }
    ...
}
```

So, how do I make my logouts permanent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Because I was logging in, in a different activity than I was logging out, the facebook Session was null when I was logging out, if I never opened the activity where I log in. This means the log out code was not running (because fbSession==null), and so the session remained open.

The solution is using the UiLifecycleHelper whenever you need to recover Session state.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what do you exactly mean with "permanent", but in my case I found that these five lines of code worked perfectly:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session != null){
    session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    Session.setActiveSession(null)
}
```

The *closeAndClearTokenInformation()* method clears any persistent token chache related to the Facebook Session.

Comment: thanks for replying. I have tried your piece of code, but can still reproduce the problem with the steps I mentioned. I don't think the issue is in the logout per se. Somehow the state doesn't persist when I kill the app after logging out and when I return to the activity with the Session.StatusCallback, the session is opened...

Comment: With uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState) you are in fact creating a new session or restoring one from the savedInstanceState, but with closeAndClearTokenInformation() you have cleared all the data, so it's impossible that the session is opened.. unless you have more than one session.

Comment: I would call `Session.setActiveSession(null)` instead of assigning `null` to the local `session` variable.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli You are right! The answer has been edited accordingly.